# Unable to scrape images from IMDB using selenium due to load-late

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to scrape images from IMDB, but I am unable to get their URLs. The IMDB has load late in their image URLs and I do not know how to proceed further with this. So can you please help me?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import urllib
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait



    mimg = []

    imdb_link = "https://www.imdb.com/search/title/?groups=top_250&sort=user_rating,desc&count=250"
    opts = Options()
    opts.add_argument("--headless")
    opts.binary_location = 'C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe'
    chrome_driver = 'C:\Project\chromedriver.exe'
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=opts, executable_path=chrome_driver)
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 3)
    driver.get(imdb_link)
    time.sleep(2)

    rmsoup = driver.page_source
    time.sleep(2)
    time.sleep(2)
    time.sleep(2)
    relsoup = BeautifulSoup(rmsoup, features='lxml')
    driver.close()

    for img in relsoup.findAll('img'):
        mimg.append(img.get('src'))
    print(mimg)
```

Comment: Refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable

Answer (score 1):

```
import time
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys # Additional
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup



target_url = "https://www.imdb.com/search/title/?groups=top_250&sort=user_rating,desc&count=250"

c_options = Options()
c_options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
browser = Chrome(executable_path='chromedriver.exe', options=c_options)
browser.get(target_url)
# Scroll down the pages
# This is very bad, crude method, but for now - I didnt wanted to go thr' JavaScript
i = 0
while (i < 101):
    body = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('body')
    body.send_keys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN)
    time.sleep(2)
    i += 1
# Soup Logic    
img_links = []
html = browser.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
advanced_div = soup.findAll('div', attrs={'class': 'lister-item mode-advanced'})
for div in advanced_div:
    img = div.find('img')
    link = img['src']
    img_links.append(link)
print(img_links)
```

This is working for me.. Does this help you?

Comment: It is only giving the first 2 image URLs in jpg which is opening but others are in png which are not opening due to load-late.

Comment: I got the point now, "Load-Late" part.. so basically the page needs to be scrolled down, for each image to be loaded properly, in ".jpg" format. I am changing the above answer code for that, in which I am doing the SCROLL part.. but very crude method of sending PAGE_DOWN Keys.

Ideally, JavaScript should do this more elegantly.

Comment: @nkpydev you should include those details in your answer as well! Adding explanations to your code will greatly improve the effectiveness of your answer.